# Couldn't open android device monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the error message:

> An error occurred. See the log file.

This is the error that I got in the log file. I have no clue what is happening. I have tried all the answers from other posts none of them is working.  Everything else is working perfectly fine. Just the android device monitor is not starting. I tried running android studio as admin as well. Any idea?

```
!SESSION 2017-12-28 15:30:05.287 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.512
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.522
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.531
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.588
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.593
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.598
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.606
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.615
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.621
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.632
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.644
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.657
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.843
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [46]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.897
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841 [84]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.924
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.931
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:06.939
!MESSAGE Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [85]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    ... 10 more
Root exception:
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [85]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.032
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.032
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.0.400.v201204
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.emf.common.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.emf.ecore_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.159
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-28 15:30:07.171
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: have you tried all options given in StackOverflow's answers?

Comment: @InziKhan yes. most of the options. probably not all.

Comment: Alright,Did error occur suddenly?Have you changed something?

Comment: It was not working at all since the beginning.

Comment: Are you running it from the android studio?

Comment: Yes, from android studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162134/discussion-between-inzikhan-and-jeevaa-v).